# Search in a implementation of LinkedList with Comparator

Tags: java, comparator

I have this interface:

```
class CustomLinkedList<T> {
    public void append(T dado);
    public void addFirst(T dado);
    public T search(Comparator<T> cmp);
    public void printObjects();
}
```

I need to search in a linked list with a Comparator, but comparators have the compare(obj1, obj2) method with 2 parameters. Here is an example of a comparator:

```
public class SearchByEmail implements Comparator<Student> {

    public SearchByEmail(String email) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Anyone have an idea of how to implement search method with the comparator?

Comment: This is pretty basic.  What code have you attempted?

Comment: I'm confused as to what the problem is - You want to find a particular item so just iterate the list and perform compare between the current element and the one you are looking for. Check and see if ever returns true.

Comment: So, do you want to compare and maybe sort values in a List or just find a value in the list and do something with it ?

Comment: OK, I think I see a problem.  Your ctor `public SearchByEmail(String email)` is wrong.  That's not how you use a Comparator.

Comment: yes, I agree, but this is how I need to implement. 

@csm_dev , using this methods, I will compare each item with what? I only have a comparator as a parameter to be used

Comment: @FairPlay I just want to search

Comment: @GustavoBarcellosdeMiranda Then you don't need Comparator, you just iterate over the collection and if the element matches what you want you do something with it, if you edit your question and post more details on what you exactly want I can post a sample code for you.

Comment: @FairPlay I agree, but I need to use comparators, I will edit with some code to be more specific

Comment: done, look below

Comment: maybe you meant [Comparable<T>](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) instead of Comparator? It has compareTo(T o) method

Answer (score 0):

An example that is horrible:

```
public T search(Comparator<T> cmp) {
    Node<T> current = first;

    do {
        if(cmp.compare(current.getElement(), null) == 0){
            return current.getElement();
        }

        current = current.getNext();

    } while (current != null);

    return null;
}
```

And the SearchByEmail:

```
public class SearchByEmail implements Comparator<Student> {
    private String email;

    public SearchByEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
        if(o1.getEmail().equals(email)) return 0;
        return 1;
    }

}
```